# What's the difference between meaning of 'A happy new year' and 'Happy new year'?

Tags: meaning, connotations

Their appearance different is the sentence has 'A' whether or not, but I have heard both... What's their difference? or no difference?

Comment: *A happy new year* is a noun phrase. *Happy new year!* is an exclamation. Both are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A happy new year

This would be said in a sentence like "have a happy new year!". It treats "happy new year" as an object.

> Happy New Year

This is just another saying that you tell someone on new years.

Both "have a happy new year" and "happy new year" are both acceptable things to say to someone on new years eve/day.